# can i click on a link that is not visible using webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

### My test case is to click on any link of a webpage. I am getting all the links and operation is performed successfully, but when i try to click on some of them then it gives following Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 31 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:00:17 -0800'
System info: host: 'ADMINPC', ip: '192.168.1.79', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b), userDataDir=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir1932_20343}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=56.0.2924.87, platform=WIN8_1, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: f622cb046f2dcc4e7ddd5621497cb602
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:638)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:274)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)
    at newpackage.AllLinks.main(AllLinks.java:32)
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. Post your code and a link to the page or at least the relevant HTML. Are you sure the element is visible? Have you tried using `WebDriverWait` to wait until each link is clickable, etc?

Answer (score -1):

This error means the link you are trying to click is not visible. Try to wait for the links to be displayed before clicking them.